# How do I get form input text from HTML on the click of the submit button, so I can use that variable in an API payload?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, api

I am trying to have a user type in a username in a field on the HTML page. After they click submit I would like that variable to be used in an API payload. After that API call is made, I would like to output the JSON response on the HTML page.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tool</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
</head>

<body>
  
<h1>Tool</h1>

<form id="myForm">
  <label for="username">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
  <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script src="scripts.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to add the username to the end of the API URL ([https://classification.svc.com/v1/users/{{variable}}](https://classification.svc.com/v1/users/%7B%7Bvariable%7D%7D))
FYI: The API key and URL are scrambled to stay confidential, but done correctly it will return a few JSON objects. I'm not worried about formatting. I just want it to be output to the HTML document.

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit = function() { 
    var thetext = (document.getElementById('username').value);
    return false;
};
var settings = {
  "url": "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://classification.svc.com/v1/users/" + thetext,
  "method": "GET",
  "timeout": 0,
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "x-api-key": "sh435ysdfgh"
  },
};

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to use the div with the "result" id to show the response.

With plain JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = response;
```

With jQuery:

```
$("#result").html(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.onsumbit` method is not synchronous, so you have to move the rest of the code into the function.

```js
document.getElementById('myForm').onsubmit = function() { 
    var thetext = (document.getElementById('username').value);
    var settings = {
         "url": "https://cors anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://classification.svc.com/v1/users/" + thetext,
         "method": "GET",
         "timeout": 0,
         "headers": {
             "Accept": "application/json",
              "x-api-key": "sh435ysdfgh"
         },
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
       console.log(response);
    });
    return false;
};
```

Comment: Instead of outputting the json response to the console, how would I display it on the HTML page?

Comment: you can do this: `document.write(JSON.stringify(response)`.